# Python, regular expressions - search dots in pandas data frame

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have pandas.dataFrame with column 'Country', head() is below:

```
0                                                  tmp   
1                     Environmental Indicators: Energy   
2                                                  tmp   
3    Energy Supply and Renewable Electricity Produc...   
4                                                  NaN   
5                                                  NaN   
6                                                  NaN   
7    Choose a country from the following drop-down ...   
8                                                  NaN   
9                                              Country
```

When I use this line:

```
energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace(r'[...]', 'a')
```

There is no change.
But when I use this line instead:

```
energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace(r'[...]', np.nan)
```

All values are NaN.

Why does only second code change output? My goal is change valuses with triple dot only.

Comment: Does this work? energy['Country'].replace('...', 'a', inplace=True)

Comment: I need change whole values, not just the triple dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want when you say "I need change whole values, not just the triple dots"?

```
mask = df.Country.str.contains(r'\.\.\.', na=False)
df.Country[mask] = 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

`.replace(r'[...]', 'a')` treats the first parameter as a regular expression, but you want to treat it literally. So, you need `.replace(r'\.\.\.', 'a')`.

As for your actual question, `.str.replace` requires a string as the second parameter. It attempts to convert `np.nan` to a string (which is not possible) and fails. For the reason not known to me, instead of raising a `TypeError`, it instead returns `np.nan` for each row.

Comment: I try .replace(r'\.\.\.', 'a'), but result is the same like before (no change in values which have '...').